# CheckBoxList OnSelectedChange event not fired

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

I Have this type of code in `Gridview` in `UpdatePanel`..
Now when I Checked `CheckBox` then it fire its `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event But When I Select two or three `CheckBox` and then uncheck any checkbox among selected then it's 
`OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is not fired..why this happen

```
       <asp:Label ID="lbltempCity" runat="server" Text="City"></asp:Label>
      <asp:CheckBoxList ID="lst" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" OnSelectedIndexChanged="hello">
                                    <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Test2</asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Test2</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
 <asp:DropDownExtender ID="DropDownExtender1" runat="server" DropArrowWidth="300px" TargetControlID="lbltempCity" DropDownControlID="lst">
                                    </asp:DropDownExtender>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("tempCity") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="15%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code it is working fine. May be cause of problem is in grid or any other control in your page. post the full code so that we can help.